# SQL server suspended SELECT query session

Tags: sql, python-3.8, sql-server-2019

I am connecting with pyodbc to SQL server with following code:

```
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'Driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;Server={server};Database={db};Trusted_Connection=yes;')
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

If I perform a SQL SELECT where I know there is only one result like the following:

```
cursor.execute('select count(*) c from mytable')
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

This results in a SQL server connection in "SUSPENDED" state as if the transaction was not closed, and read locks seem to remain held on the relevant table.

What is the best way to ensure that the transaction is closed on the connection, if I intend to later on reuse the same cursor and connection to perform other requests?

Should I close the cursor and reopen?

I am using Python 3 on SQL Server 2016/2019.

Comment: Did you happen to run the profiler to see the trace on what queries being run?

Comment: Yes, it shows the SELECT query was executed.

Comment: to your last question: yes, best practice is to always close the connection after you executed the query (conn.close()) if you e.g.  intend to make a function that runs and repeats for a while.

Comment: Set `autocommit=true`

Comment: The code above that I have has it. And I wonder if autocommit is relevant for a SELECT?